# How can I append an element to a specific area of the page using pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendchild

I am trying to append an image to a specific area of my page (the middle). At the moment the image is appearing at the very bottom of my page. Could anyone advise me how to change the location of where the image appears?

```
    function picture(){
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'youwin.png';
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
} picture();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a great use case for `position: absolute` in your CSS. I've whipped up a little example, [is this what you're looking to do?](https://codepen.io/nimaboscarino/pen/yLBJaaY).

In the example that I linked, I wrapped a DIV around the image to make putting the image in a the centre a bit easier, but you can do this by styling the image on its own as well.

```css
image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Play with the `left` and `top` values to move your image around!

If you want the image to be centred, I think the easiest thing to do is wrap a DIV around the image and style the div instead. Try `text-align: center` like in my example.

When you're looking at how to style the DIV, you can even take a look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for some options!